# How to read data from azure VM data disk via app service which resides in same Vnet?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, virtual-machine, vnet

I am trying to read the data from azure VM data disk via app service, both are in the same Vnet and i have already configured the Vnet integration.

But I  dont have any idea on how to access the vm from app service

Comment: Please add more information, reading this my guess is what you are asking is how to mount a disk that is attached to a VM to an Azure App Service and leave it attached to the VM as well.  Also explaining what you are trying to accomplish might help us understand what to suggest.

Comment: @CameronVetter I am trying access the files from VM data disk using app service

Comment: What did you have a try? Is there any error message?

Comment: @NancyXiong using network share

Answer (score 0):

Due to the App Service sandbox explicitly does not allow access to the ports necessary for SMB protocol (137/138/139/445), I am afraid we can not use network share in the app service. Check this article link that mentioned it under Restricted Outgoing Ports: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox.

Alternatively, you can use [Azure File Share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/storageservices/file-service-rest-api) and access using REST API.

You also could consider storing your data on Azure storage then either [attaching Azure Storage to a Linux container App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?pivots=container-linux) or [attaching Azure Storage Files as a network share to a windows container in App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?pivots=container-windows).